# Next.js adding a css class to Link

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

How does one add a css class to a [Link component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) in Next.js?

```
<Link
    className="app-subnav__link"
    href="/globalSettings"
>
    Settings overview
</Link>
```

It doesn't like the above! ES Link is throwing an error:

[image]

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this (available in **NextJS v13**):

```
<Link href="/globalSettings" className="app-subnav__link"> 
    Settings Overview
</Link>
```

NextJS v12 and older:

```
<Link href="/globalSettings"> 
    <a className="app-subnav__link">Settings Overview</a>
</Link>
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

[Update](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/codemods#new-link): in NextJS v13 The next/link child can no longer be `<a>`. Add the `legacyBehavior` prop to use the legacy behavior or remove the `<a>` to upgrade. A codemod is available to automatically upgrade your code.

---

Any apps still using **NextJS v12 or older** should use the old approach, which was to give the `Link` an `<a>` child and style that:

```
<Link href="/globalSettings"> 
    <a className="app-subnav__link">Settings Overview</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Is this a wrong answer? according to the NextJS document it's correct.

Comment: you're right.  My apologies - At first glance this looked very wrong but indeed it is the way to do it.  Deleting my previous comment so as to not to confuses anyone...

Answer (score 5):

In next version 13 you can use it directly in the Link component. Here is no need to include the a tag.

Answer (score -2):

apply the style to "a" also work for me

```css
parentElement {
 a {
  padding:10px
 }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question OP has asked, as they want to specifically add a style to a single `Link` and then style it.

Answer (score -4):

enclose link inside a `<div>` . Apply className in the `<div>` . This might not be the right way to do it but it works